# Unresolved External Symbol receiveThread (that's the entry point for _beginthread)

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I'm trying to get a UDP connection working for a game I'm making, the input for the socket is read via a second thread, so the game can continue running while it's waiting for messages. I got it to work in a separate project, but when porting it over to my game code I get an Unresolved External Symbol error:

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl receiveThread(void *)" (?receiveThread@@YAXPAX@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Network::setupServerUDP(void)" (?setupServerUDP@Network@@QAE_NXZ)).

I've googled this and everyone says the Runtime Library should be set to Multi-threaded, which I did (In MVS 2010 I don't think it's even possible to set it to single-threaded) but it doesn't resolve the error.
I'm sure it's just some stupid option set to the wrong thing somewhere. But I just can't think of what it is.

I've included ws2tcpip.h and I've linked to the correct library: #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib").

The only difference between my test project and the game project is that the test project was a Console application and the other is a Windows application, but I don't see why that should be any problem. Thoughts?

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,

Maxim

Comment: I don't recognise `receiveThread()`. Is one of your functions?

Comment: Why does the title say "Unresolved (...) _beginthread" but in the text "unresolved (...) receiveThread"?

Comment: Yes, it's the function I use for the thread. setupServerUDP is the function for setting the sockets and everything and it calls the _beginthread(receiveThread,0,&params); (params is a struct used to get the socket handel and a list of clients to the thread).

Comment: @RedX the _beginthread gets receiveThread as a parameter to indicate which function to use for the thread.

Comment: Have you declared the beginThread function before you pass it to _beginThread?

Comment: Jup, at the top of the code. void receiveThread(void *);

Comment: Oh wait, you mean the _beginthread? If I add #define _beginthread at the top it compiles. But I'm not sure that's what's supposed to happen :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unresolved function is not `_beginthread`, it's `receiveThread`. That's your function - the thread entry point that you provide as a parameter to `_beginthread`. Did you write that function *with the right calling convention*? Is it really `cdecl`? If you declare it as cdecl but implement without an explicit calling convention, that would cause a link error like this. For example, this code would cause a link error:

```
extern "C" { void receiveThread(void*); } //There's a cdecl function somewhere

//...

_beginthread(receiveThread, 0, 0); //Let's refer to it

//...

void receiveThread(void *p) //But this is not it! It's stdcall.
{
     //Do something
}
```

To fix, make sure your implementation of `receiveThread` uses the cdecl convention or is declared as `extern "C"`.

For the record, `_beginthreadex` expects a stdcall function, not cdecl. With `_beginthreadex`, you don't have to worry about conventions.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the linker cannot find the implementation for the function `receiveThread` which I'm guessing is declared in ws2tcpip.h

If `Ws2_32.lib` contains the implementation, try adding it to linker -> additional dependencies -> inputs under the properties menu for the project, assuming you're using visual studio.